# Vagrant unable to run vagrant halt, it throws error with my box file. even the vagrant up throws the error

Tags: vagrant, vbox, vagrant-ssh

PS D:\ubuntu20.04> vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

PS D:\ubuntu20.04>

Comment: Vagrant up also doesn't work.==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => D:/ubuntu20.04
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

you need to force it
try this :

```
vagrant halt -f
```